# VBA conditional formating with color scale

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have this excel table with some data and conditional formatting with these colors. As the months go by, I am adding new columns and rows to the table and would like to have via retain the conditional formatting as the numbers change. I've tried two methods doing the copy and pastespecial pasteformat, and also autofill for the cells. but somehow conditional formatting isn't working, e.g. the color is supposed to be orange when the number is small but my new column/row some how does not follow the rules even when numbers become large. any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: How are you currently adding the rows/columns?

Comment: Feels as though VB solution would be over engineering here. Is there a need to insert rows/columns? why not tweak the existing rule `Home>Conditional Formatting>Manage Rules>This Worksheet` and adjust the range it applies to?